# How to resize JPanels individually?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am trying to design a simple gui interface. The frame consists of a main panel which contains another four panels "Staff Details", "Job Details" "Photo" and buttons. The output is as follows:

[image: output]

I used gridLayout for all the panels except for the "buttons panel" which has borderLayout.

Now I want to reduce the height of the bottom two panels so it won't have the extra space. How do I do that?

Here is the code for the "photo" panel and "button" panel. Both panels now have flow layout.

```
        photoPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,70));
        photoPanel.add(browsebx);
        photoPanel.add(browseBtn);


        btnPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,70));
        btnPanel.add(addBtn);
        btnPanel.add(editBtn);
        btnPanel.add(deleteBtn);
        btnPanel.add(cancelBtn);
```

Comment: why did you stopped to post an SSCCE/MCVE

Comment: the code is just too long...I also didnt want to provide only a part of the code since it won't be compilable

Comment: OK up to you, voting to close as too broad

Comment: I just thought it would be more helpful for others having the same problem if I didn't post the code as it is very difficult to read through a long code

Comment: SSCCE/MCVE is max about 150 code lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main panel is using a `GridLayout`, which means all four panels will be the exact same size. Don't use a GridLayout.

Instead maybe you can use a `GridBagLayout`. This allows your to add each panel to a specific grid, but each panel will maintain its preferred size as determines by the layout manager used on each of the individual panels.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more information and examples.

Remember each of the 4 child panels can use a different layout manager if desired. For example you would probably want to use a `FlowLayout` for the buttons panel.

Comment: Thanks a lot...I was using grid layout for simplicity but it is producing the extra space

Answer (score 1):

you can use this.

```
jPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(x, y));

jPanel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(x, y));  
jPanel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(x, y));
```

Comment: Do I have to use all three?

Comment: nope, just use the first one. if it didn't solve, use all of them.

Comment: It didn't work... I tried setPreferredSize and then all three of them together.

Comment: did you set the jpanel size first before adding it to jframe?

Comment: yes...I have added the code for "Photo Panel" and "Button Panel"

Comment: [Don't use `setPreferredSize()` when you really mean to override `getPreferredSize()`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513).